# Foodb api fetch react native

Tags: react-native, api, rest

Hello I am a beginner in mobile app development. I am doing project in react native.In my app I need to fetch the food details from ***foodb website*** using API. I tried in postman to get response but I am getting error.

[image: In foodb website they provided like this but I am getting Api missing error]

[image]

Error:

```
  {
    "error": "food_name is missing, api_key is missing"
}
```

Kindly guide me to resolve this problem. Thanks in Advance

Comment: I tried with axios too.But I am getting the same error sir.I will add my axios code with this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add parameter as query parameters:

```
curl -X GET 'https://foodb.ca/api/v1/foodreport/food?food_name=Angelicaa&api_key=d9b6cec3eb561db6f920a0797ba49f3e'
```

Comment: Hello sir. I didn't know more about CURL. Can you explain this code with axios

Comment: Don’t send http headers, just add the api key and the food in the url

Comment: Ok sir.Understood